# CSS: div won't float left (float: left)

Tags: css

I can't get `#sitedescription` to float left, so it appears underneath `#title-link` on [this site](http://test.doig.com.au/MHM/).

```
.header #logo {position: relative; width: 90px; float: left;}
.header #title-link {position: relative; height: 20px; width: 200px; margin-bottom: 11px; float: left;}
.header #sitedescription {position: relative; height: 14px; width: 200px; float: left;}
.header #sitedescription h2 {position: relative; font-size: 11px; color: #622C82;}

<div class="logo">
    <div id="logo"><a href="/"><img id="header-logo" src="/wp-content/themes/madhatmedia/images/header-logo.png" data-pin-nopin="true"></a></div>
    <div id="title-link"><a href="/"><h1 class="title">Mad Hat Media</h1></a></div>
    <div id="sitedescription"><h2>Marketing Agency Fremantle</h2></div>
</div>
```

The header needs to look like this:
[image]

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: updated screenshot]Removing float left from .header #sitedescription will add it under title.

```
.header #sitedescription {position: relative; height: 14px; width: 300px;}
```

Comment: Thanks VNP. That solution doesn't make sense to me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

hi can you make it clear:both as below code (add that extra code in that class) and increase the font size as you wish

```
.header #sitedescription {
position: relative;
height: 14px;
width: 300px;
display: block;
clear: right;
left: -27px;
}
```

[image: Demo]

thanks